# Is it possible to call a scala method passed as a parameter in a Java method?

Tags: java, scala

I'm working with Play framework via a Java project and I'd like to pass my templates (Scala functions) as parameters to one of my Java method.

I'd like to do something like this :

```
public static Result ok(ScalaFunction template, Object obj) {
    // do some work, then :
    return ok(template.render(obj));
}

MyClass.ok(views.html.mytemplate, SomeModel.find.findList());
```

Of course, this doesn't work. I supposed `views.html.mytemplate` is a class, so I switched to `views.html.mytemplate.class` and `public static Result ok(Class template, Object obj)` in my method, but I can't call `render` on it.

Is it possible to do something like this ?

If someone knows a better alternative, what I'm trying to achieve is either return a JSON representation of `obj` if the Accept header is "*application/json*", or the compiled template (given in first parameter) if the Accept header is "*text/html*".

Comment: try template.apply(obj)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but there is no `apply` method for the `Class template` parameter

Comment: If your `template` is a genuine Scala function, you can do something like `public static Result ok(scala.Function1[RenderedTemplate,Result] template, Object obj)`. Scala's functions are represented as instances of `FunctionN`.

Comment: I can't apparently find RenderedTemplate, you sure about the name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say your `Scala` function takes and returns an `Object`, hence of type `Function1<Object, Object>` then your Java method should look like this:

```
public Result ok(Function1<Object, Object> template, Object obj) {
    // do some work, then:
    return ok(template.render(obj));
}
```